# thread exiting with uncaught nullpointerexception

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

This app works fine in Note 2 running 4.1 but i get a "Thread exiting with uncaught exception" and NullPointerexception in 4.2 running htc one.I assure you there are no faults in id matching(I've cross checked several times).The app basically outputs the highest resoulution image from Google.
here are the logcats

```
11-15 12:18:54.589: D/dalvikvm(14843): Late-enabling CheckJNI
11-15 12:18:54.700: W/ResourceType(14843): Skipping entry 0x7f040005 in package table 0 because it is not complex!
11-15 12:18:54.700: W/ResourceType(14843): Skipping entry 0x7f040005 in package table 0 because it is not complex!
11-15 12:18:54.710: W/ResourceType(14843): Skipping entry 0x7f040005 in package table 0 because it is not complex!
11-15 12:18:54.710: W/ResourceType(14843): Skipping entry 0x7f040005 in package table 0 because it is not complex!
11-15 12:18:54.750: D/TAG(14843): MainActivity has started.
11-15 12:18:54.800: D/libEGL(14843): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_adreno200.so
11-15 12:18:54.800: D/libEGL(14843): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno200.so
11-15 12:18:54.810: D/libEGL(14843): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno200.so
11-15 12:18:54.810: I/Adreno200-EGL(14843): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:269>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_JB_VANILLA.04.02.02.60.051_msm8960_JB_VANILLA_CL2997615_release_AU (CL2997615)
11-15 12:18:54.810: I/Adreno200-EGL(14843): Build Date: 04/11/13 Thu
11-15 12:18:54.810: I/Adreno200-EGL(14843): Local Branch: 
11-15 12:18:54.810: I/Adreno200-EGL(14843): Remote Branch: quic/mako_jb_mr1
11-15 12:18:54.810: I/Adreno200-EGL(14843): Local Patches: NONE
11-15 12:18:54.810: I/Adreno200-EGL(14843): Reconstruct Branch: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_JB_VANILLA.04.02.02.60.051 +  NOTHING
11-15 12:18:54.850: D/OpenGLRenderer(14843): Enabling debug mode 0
11-15 12:18:58.704: D/TAG(14843): In button listener
11-15 12:18:58.704: D/TAG(14843): String has been added!!!
11-15 12:18:58.714: D/TAG(14843): Making the fragment now!!
11-15 12:18:58.714: D/TAG(14843): Arguments passed!!
11-15 12:18:58.714: D/TAG(14843): Fragment made!!
11-15 12:18:58.724: D/AndroidRuntime(14843): Shutting down VM
11-15 12:18:58.734: W/dalvikvm(14843): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41bba930)
11-15 12:18:58.754: E/AndroidRuntime(14843): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-15 12:18:58.754: E/AndroidRuntime(14843): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-15 12:18:58.754: E/AndroidRuntime(14843):    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:394)
11-15 12:18:58.754: E/AndroidRuntime(14843):    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
11-15 12:18:58.754: E/AndroidRuntime(14843):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2159)
11-15 12:18:58.754: E/AndroidRuntime(14843):    at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1831)
11-15 12:18:58.754: E/AndroidRuntime(14843):    at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:674)
11-15 12:18:58.754: E/AndroidRuntime(14843):    at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:735)
11-15 12:18:58.754: E/AndroidRuntime(14843):    at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1652)
11-15 12:18:58.754: E/AndroidRuntime(14843):    at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1994)
11-15 12:18:58.754: E/AndroidRuntime(14843):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14015)
11-15 12:18:58.754: E/AndroidRuntime(14843):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
11-15 12:18:58.754: E/AndroidRuntime(14843):    at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:702)
11-15 12:18:58.754: E/AndroidRuntime(14843):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14015)
11-15 12:18:58.754: E/AndroidRuntime(14843):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
11-15 12:18:58.754: E/AndroidRuntime(14843):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
11-15 12:18:58.754: E/AndroidRuntime(14843):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14015)
11-15 12:18:58.754: E/AndroidRuntime(14843):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
11-15 12:18:58.754: E/AndroidRuntime(14843):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1663)
11-15 12:18:58.754: E/AndroidRuntime(14843):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1521)
11-15 12:18:58.754: E/AndroidRuntime(14843):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
11-15 12:18:58.754: E/AndroidRuntime(14843):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14015)
11-15 12:18:58.754: E/AndroidRuntime(14843):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
11-15 12:18:58.754: E/AndroidRuntime(14843):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
11-15 12:18:58.754: E/AndroidRuntime(14843):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14015)
11-15 12:18:58.754: E/AndroidRuntime(14843):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
11-15 12:18:58.754: E/AndroidRuntime(14843):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1892)
11-15 12:18:58.754: E/AndroidRuntime(14843):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1711)
11-15 12:18:58.754: E/AndroidRuntime(14843):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:989)
11-15 12:18:58.754: E/AndroidRuntime(14843):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4351)
11-15 12:18:58.754: E/AndroidRuntime(14843):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
11-15 12:18:58.754: E/AndroidRuntime(14843):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
11-15 12:18:58.754: E/AndroidRuntime(14843):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
11-15 12:18:58.754: E/AndroidRuntime(14843):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
11-15 12:18:58.754: E/AndroidRuntime(14843):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
11-15 12:18:58.754: E/AndroidRuntime(14843):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-15 12:18:58.754: E/AndroidRuntime(14843):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-15 12:18:58.754: E/AndroidRuntime(14843):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5227)
11-15 12:18:58.754: E/AndroidRuntime(14843):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-15 12:18:58.754: E/AndroidRuntime(14843):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-15 12:18:58.754: E/AndroidRuntime(14843):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
11-15 12:18:58.754: E/AndroidRuntime(14843):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
11-15 12:18:58.754: E/AndroidRuntime(14843):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

MainActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Log.d("TAG","MainActivity has started.");
    drawer_enter=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.drawer_enter);
    list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
    //image_button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.image_button);
    //image_button.setOnClickListener(button);
    drawer_enter.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {

                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(
                      Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(drawer_enter.getWindowToken(), 0);

        Log.d("TAG","In button listener");
        inflateString(drawer_enter.getText().toString());
        MakeFrag();

                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });


    drawer=(DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    listen=new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,drawer,R.drawable.ic_launcher,0,0){
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
             getActionBar().setTitle("History");
         }
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
             getActionBar().setTitle("Best Google Image");
         }
    };
    drawer.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(listen);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

}

/*private OnClickListener button=new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View theView) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(
                  Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(drawer_enter.getWindowToken(), 0);

    Log.d("TAG","In button listener");

    //int num=inflateString(drawer_enter.getText().toString());
    MakeFrag();
    }
};*/

private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener{

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
            long arg3) {
        MakeDrawerFrag(position);
        //drawer.closeDrawer(arg0);
    }

}

public void MakeFrag(){
    Log.d("TAG", "Making the fragment now!!");
    Fragment fragment=new ImageFragment();
    Bundle args=new Bundle();
    args.putString(ImageFragment.ARG_IMAGE_SEARCH,drawer_enter.getText().toString());
    fragment.setArguments(args);

    FragmentManager fragmentManager=getFragmentManager();
    Log.d("TAG", "Arguments passed!!");
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_layout, fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
    Log.d("TAG", "Fragment made!!");

}



private void inflateString(String name)
{
    int i=0;
    for(i=0;i<names.length;i++){
        if(names[i]==null){
            names[i]=name;
            break;
        }
    }
    list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.list_item,names));
    Log.d("TAG","String has been added!!!");
}
```

ImageFragment.java

```
public class ImageFragment extends Fragment{
        public static final String ARG_IMAGE_SEARCH = "image_search";
        public Bitmap done=null;
        private String search="",newSearch="";
        private ImageView photo=null;
        /*public ImageFragment() {
            // Empty constructor required for fragment subclasses
        }*/

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            Log.d("TAG","making the view of the Fragment!!!");
            search=getArguments().getString(ARG_IMAGE_SEARCH);
            int i;

            for(i=0;i<search.length();i++){
                if(search.charAt(i)==' '){
                    newSearch+="%20";
                }
                else{
                    newSearch+=search.charAt(i);

                }
            }
            Log.d("TAG",newSearch);
            new ImageLoader().execute(newSearch);
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_view, container, false);
            photo=(ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.image_view);
            photo.setImageBitmap(done);
            getActivity().setTitle(getArguments().getString(ARG_IMAGE_SEARCH));
            return rootView;
        }





private class ImageLoader extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Void>{
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(String... args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try{
        Log.d("TAG", "Background thread has started!!");
        URL url=new URL("https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?" +
                "v=1.0&q="+args[0]);
        HttpURLConnection connection=(HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        String urlData;
        StringBuilder builder=new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
        while((urlData=reader.readLine()) != null){
            builder.append(urlData);
        }
        JSONObject first=new JSONObject(builder.toString());
        int i,larg = 0;
        for(i=0;i<2;i++){
            if((first.getJSONObject("responseData").getJSONArray("results").getJSONObject(i).getInt("width"))>first.getJSONObject("responseData").getJSONArray("results").getJSONObject(i+1).getInt("width")){
                larg=i;
            }
            else larg=i+1;
        }
        String image=first.getJSONObject("responseData").getJSONArray("results").getJSONObject(larg).getString("url");
        URL imgUrl = new URL(image);
        HttpURLConnection imgConnection=(HttpURLConnection)imgUrl.openConnection();
        InputStream input=imgConnection.getInputStream();
        done=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        Log.d("TAG","Bitmap has been formed!!");

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    return null;


    }
protected void onPostExecute(Void result){
    photo.setImageBitmap(done);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is in the ImageFragment onCreate here:

```
search=getArguments().getString(ARG_IMAGE_SEARCH);
```

I believe you're getting a null pointer because you aren't getting any arguments -- you aren't getting any arguments because the Fragment isn't receiving them -- I'll show you how to fix it at the end.

Just to make sure it's not getting any arguments, do this -- Comment out everything in the fragment's onCreateView, then make it like this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_view, container, false);

try {
    search=getArguments().getString(ARG_IMAGE_SEARCH);
    Log.d("onCreateView",search); // this will print out the search string to logcat
    } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();  // or throw an exception and print it to logcat
    }

return rootView;
}
```

This will either verify that search is getting the arguments (which it probably isn't) and print our the search string, or throw an exception. If it is throwing an exception, then proceed...

To solve the problem, you first need to add this to your Fragment:

```
static ImageFragment newInstance(String string){
    ImageFragment fragment = new ImageFragment();

    Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putString(ImageFragment.ARG_IMAGE_SEARCH, string);

    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}
```

Then in your activity, start a new ImageFragment, you call it like this:

```
Fragment newImageFrag = ImageFragment.newInstance(WHATEVER_STRING_ARGUMENT_YOU_NEED_TO_PASS);
// from here add or replace the fragment as normal
```

After you do these two things, when the newImageFrag gets created via the newInstance and the passed string, you will be able to call

```
search=getArguments().getString(ARG_IMAGE_SEARCH);
```

and actually get the argument. I hope I understood your question correctly, and I hope this helps.

Comment: You're right about the fact that the problem is in the onCreateView but I'm pretty sure the arguments are being passed.When i tried the same app in 4.1 jelly bean,there was no problem whatsoever in passing the arguments.I think the problem can be in the declaration of ViewGroup. As for your solution,it didn't work as it kept asking me to make a new class by the name newinstance which is not needed.

Comment: Even th first line of onCreateView (the Log.d one )did not get printed in the LogCats as u can see. So the NullPointerException must be occuring right in the declaration of onCreateView.Any help regarding this would be greatly appreciated.